# Detect (or best guess of) incoming string encoding in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, decoding, utf-16

I was wondering if there are known methods to detect (or give a best guess of) the encoding of a particular string in Java.

I know that you always need some additional meta-data to tell what the encoding is, and there are best practices etc., but the situation I'm in, I need to give the best approximation.

A solution -- or a pointer -- to programatically distinguishing between UTF-8 and UTF-16 is also welcome.

Comment: What does UTF-16 and UTF-8 have to do with URL encoding?

Comment: The only reasonable way is to make them specify the encoding (using ASCII!) first as some sort of metadata. Never guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utf-8 encoding should be easy to verify:

> UTF-8 strings can be fairly reliably recognized as such by a simple heuristic algorithm.
>   [from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences)

Take a look at [this site to see the algorithm](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8)

Comment: Accepting this as the right answer since he pointed me to an algorithm rather than an existing toolkit.

I actually also like the method used here: http://www.opensourcejavaphp.net/java/groovy/groovy/util/CharsetToolkit.java.html

Answer (score 2):

Look at ICU4J which includes a character detector

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), in particular [BOMInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html).

Comment: Yeah but I don't have the BOM or any other necessary metadata to help me out here. That's why I said a best guess of.